# add variable on array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript code for change automatic placeholder from change keyword. This is the smallest part of the code :

```
 $("#addrow").on("click", function () {

            counter = $('#myTable tr').length -1;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        ....
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="keyword' + counter + '" placeholder="add keyword in here.." style="width: 425px;"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="-"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        //if (counter == 4) $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);

        counter++;

        $("#list_field"+counter).change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'all'){
        $("input[name=keyword]").attr('placeholder', 'add keyword in here');
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'chrom'){
        $("input[name=keyword]").attr('placeholder', 'ex: 8');
    } });


});
```

that was the problem for me is how to add the variable "counter" in `"$("input[name=keyword]").attr('placeholder', 'add keyword in here');"`. is like this? ->

```
$("input[name=keyword]").counter.attr('placeholder', 'add keyword in here');
```

sorry I am still learning about javascript. thanks for your solution.

Comment: You mean that you want the variable in the placeholer?
`$("input[name=keyword]").attr('placeholder', counter);`, sorry I think I did not fully understand your problem

Comment: Also, I'll mention that it's more common/best practice to use the `data-` prefix for custom attributes. So `.attr('data-placeholder', counter)` to write and `.attr('data-placeholder')` to read. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Well, `placeholder` attribute is not a plain data one; it's visualized by the browser, giving the (sort of) default value for an input. But in general you're right - it's better to use `data-*` attrs for passing the values into JS.

Comment: Thanks @raina77ow, I was not aware that the `placeholder` attribute was a part of the HTML spec.

Comment: in my html code, there is a name <input type="text" name="keyword0" placeholder="add keyword in here.."> , so variable "counter" it for keyword0, keyword1, keyword2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want add a variable in text of placeholder here is the code

```
var counter =1 ; 
$("input[name=keyword]").attr('placeholder', 'add keyword in here '+counter);
```

if you want discriminate each input you can add an id

```
var counter =1 ; 
$("input[name=keyword]").attr('id', counter);
```

also you can find an element with css selector nth-child(number-of-item)

html

```
<input class="input" palceholder="blabla1">
<input class="input" palceholder="blabla2">
<input class="input" palceholder="blabla3">
```

javascript

```
var counter =1 ; 
$(".inputs:nth-child("+counter+")")
```

Comment: I want to access the html code on the input variable name "keyword0", keyword1, keyword2, etc. And 0,1,2 in javascript is that if the "counter" variable.

Comment: $("input[name=keyword"+counter+"]")